# Question about Sample Size Imbalance for Dichotomous Moderator

Tags: interaction

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I've looked in multiple places and can't find any discussion about it.

I have a model where gender is the moderator (1 = female; 0 = male), but the number of females and males is very imbalanced (e.g., 50 women and 324 males).

Would this large sample imbalance somehow effect the results (e.g., skew the results or otherwise make this type of analysis problematic) and, if so, can anyone please direct me to some citations that discuss this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is fine. You will have less power to detect differences in the slope of the predictor (i.e., the moderation effect) with an unbalanced vs balanced design with the same total sample size, and you will have less power to detect departures from zero for slope of females than for the slope of males because your sample size is smaller for females. Otherwise, this is not problematic at all.